# Convex, absorbing sets and nonempty interior

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $A$ be a convex, absorbing subset of a real Banach space $X$ with the additional property that the closure $\rm{cl}(A)$ contains an open ball around $0\in X$.

Does this imply that already $A$ itself contains an open ball around 0?

(I hope that this additional property is already a consequence of Baire's lemma. But please correct me if this is wrong...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope that this additional property is already a consequence of Baire's lemma.

$X$ is a complete metric space, so it is  of second category. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160943/show-a-closed-convex-absorbing-set-in-a-topological-space-nonmeger-in-its-self) thread is proved that $\overline{A}$ contains a neighborhood of $0$.

> Does this imply that already $A$ itself contains an open ball around $0$?

No. Let $X=\ell^2$ and $A_0$ be a set consisting of standard unit vectors $e_n$, $n\in\Bbb N$, $A_1$ be a maximal linear independent subset of unit length vectors containing $A_0$, and $A$ be a convex hull of the set $A_1\cup (-A_1)$. Then each vector $x\in X$ has a unique representation as a linear combination of vectors of $A_1$ and $A$ is an absorbing set of $X$. Now for each natural $n$ put $x_n=\tfrac 2n\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$. Then $x_n\not\in A$, but $\|x_n\|=\tfrac 2{\sqrt{n}}$, so a sequence $\{x_n\}$  converges to zero.

Comment: Wow, that sounds really good! It is a nice example! Thank you very much!